# How to display the creation date of a badge earning with merit gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, merit-gem

I'm trying to find a way to display in a View the badge & the "granted_at" record. It would render (in the view) :

```
 <% @profil.badges.each do |badge| %>                                                                       
   <%= image_tag (badge.custom_fields[:image]), badge.granted_at %>
 <% end %>
```

Should I enable the MeritObserver to get this on the view ? Or there is a simpler solution?

(I'm on Rails 5)

## EDIT

Thanks to TuteC, we have an answer :

```
<% @profil.sash.badges_sashes.each do |badge_sash| %>
    <%= image_tag (badge_sash.badge.custom_fields[:image]) %><%= badge_sash.created_at %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got to go through `sash` and `badges_sashes` relations:

```
 <% @profil.sash.badges_sashes.each do |badge_sash| %>
   <%= image_tag(badge_sash.badge.custom_fields[:image]), badge_sash.created_at %>
 <% end %>
```

You can read about merit internals in https://github.com/merit-gem/merit/wiki/General-merit-workflow.

Comment: Hi TuteC, your answer was correct but it would'nt work with the 'badge_sash.created_at' in the 'image_tag'. I made an edit on my question. Great work for Merit, it's just perfect ;)

Comment: Glad it worked, thanks! Don't forget to mark the question as answered, will also edit my answer.